# How to make a path with text document

Tags: python

I am making a level editor, where i need to save the "Maps" they build.
And they can make there own name to the "Map".

but i can't use "\" because, yeah i don't know why(I know it is something about escape sequences)  and i hope there is either a way to get around it or use another method
and i am a noob at this so i don't know to make that a code:

```
The_name = "Easy_map" #that's what they called it

path = "levels\" + the_name + ".txt" #making the path
```

I expect the variable path to be levels\Easy_map.txt
but the output is 
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
because i use "\"

Comment: Hey Anders, this is a common problem we've all had to deal with!    Check out the link that Ankit Agrawal commented.  We have to escape a backslash for it to be used in strings, the other post will explain it for you.

Answer (score 2):

The backslash `\` is the escape character. If you want to include a backslash in your string, you need to escape it (preface it with the escape character). So, the string literal `'\\'` would print out as `\`